# How to modify digital twins management URL?

Tags: azure, azure-digital-twins

I am a newbie in Azure Digital Twins and Azure Management API, and I following this document, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/tutorial-facilities-setup

In the section "Deploy Digital Twins", part 5, it asks about modifying the management URL and I don't know how to do that. Maybe this is very easy things for many, but I am new in this and I really confused about how to do that change. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your confusion, the word "modify" implies you're making a change. What is meant here is that you need to copy the URL that is displayed on your instance to any text editor and change it. You will be relacing '**swagger**' to '**api/v1.0/**' See below:

```
original:
https://yourDigitalTwinsName.yourLocation.azuresmartspaces.net/management/swagger
changed:
https://yourDigitalTwinsName.yourLocation.azuresmartspaces.net/management/api/v1.0/
```

You will need this URL when you get to [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/tutorial-facilities-setup#configure-the-provisioning-sample) in the tutorial.

Comment: thanks for your answer! your reference back to this page. would you mind correct that?

Comment: perfect .. I will continue this and I will mark your answer after ... thanks again!